# MySQL Database Query in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

I'm a beginner and have done multiple successful queries to my database in JAVA but one of my queries is returning something that I don't understand. 
What's printing is: [Ljava.lang.String;@6b081032
And what actually should be printing are names of conditions.  So if my query is suppose to return 7 condition names, it will print "[Ljava.lang.String;@6b081032" seven times.

Below is my code where I'm testing out a method that I've been having a problem with.  What does "[Ljava.lang.String;@6b081032" mean?  Thanks.

```
public class Test {
 static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/masters";  //providing the host, port and database name
    static String username = "christine";
    static String password = "password";

    static PreparedStatement pst = null;
    static ResultSet rs = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        String[] test = dxNameByName(2);
            for(int i=0; i<test.length; i++)
                {   
                    System.out.println(test);
                }

}


public static String[] dxNameByName(int num){

    Connection con = null;
    ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();     
    String[] result = new String[list.size()];           

    try{
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);  //establishes a connection to the database
        pst = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM diagnosis WHERE  diag_region_fk = '" + num+ "';");                                                                                                                                                
        rs = pst.executeQuery(); 

            while (rs.next())                   
            {                                   
                list.add(rs.getString("diagnosis_name"));
            }
         result = list.toArray(result);     
         }catch(SQLException e){     
             e.printStackTrace();    
         }
             finally{
        try { if (rs != null) rs.getStatement().close(); } catch (Exception e) {};
        try { if (pst != null) pst.close(); } catch (Exception e) {};
        try { if (con != null) con.close(); } catch (Exception e) {};
    }

return result;

}
}
```

Comment: Why make the computer go to all of the trouble of building an ArrayList, and then just return an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the array itself, not the contents of the array. Use [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));
```

That gives the nicest looking output IMHO (example: `[something, something, something]`).

---

You could also iterate through all the values and print them one at a time:

```
for(int i=0; i<test.length; i++)
{   
    System.out.println(test[i]);
}
```

The output is a little less nice though, since each content is printed on it's own line.

Answer (score 1):

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@6b081032
```

this means that the printed variable type is `String[]`

In order to output the result of the query, change your code to the following:

```
System.out.println(test[i]);
```